# Full Calendar Widget is not displaying in browser

Tags: jquery, css, calendar, sitecore

I'm using this https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/SymSoft_Event_Calendar_Module.aspx for sitecore and can't seem to get the calender to display. I'm getting an error in firebug TypeError: $ is not a function which is from this script

```
<script type=text/javascript>
    $(document).ready(function ($) { 
         $('body').FullCalendarWidget('#maincontent_0_content_0_pnlCalendar',
         'http://devosinstitute.umd.edu:80/Ajax/Ajax.ashx?id=e7cbaa1a-c9e3-4aa9-90f8-d2e6baa41fd6&calendars=05120D6A-C8DE-42C1-861A-99C9162CC9B0',
         'prev,next', 
         'title', 
         'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay', 
          false,
          ''
    ); }(jQuery))
</script>
```

http://placer.ca.gov/EventCalendar.aspx is using the same module for sitecore and I have compared code but can't seem to figure out the issue.

Comment: Looks like jQuery is not correctly attached to page(or isn't attached at all).

Comment: yes <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> just like the website im comparing to.

Comment: Try to change `$(document).ready` to `jQuery(document).ready`

Comment: I can see to figure out where or how that code is being populated. I've looked in the main layout, and various sublayouts.

Comment: I found the source. It was in a code behind file of a sublayout. It worked. Thanks Marek!

Comment: The scoping and call of the [self-executing anonymous function](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/) is not correct, it should be like this: http://pastebin.com/yh75mtqG

Comment: @leflis you should update your code with what jammykam wrote

Comment: this was the actual code that I changed.(function ($) { $('body').FullCalendarWidget('#" + pnlCalendar.ClientID + "', " + "'http://" + Request.Url.Host + ":"+Request.Url.Port + "/Ajax/Ajax.ashx" + "?id=" + Sitecore.Context.Item.ID.ToGuid().ToString() + "&calendars=" + calendarString.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "") + "', 'prev,next', 'title', 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay', false, '');  }(jQuery));
it also works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The scoping and call of the [self-executing anonymous function](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/) is not correct, it should be like this:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('body').FullCalendarWidget('#maincontent_0_content_0_pnlCalendar',
            '/Ajax/Ajax.ashx?id=e7cbaa1a-c9e3-4aa9-90f8-d2e6baa41fd6&calendars=05120D6A-C8DE-42C1-861A-99C9162CC9B0',
            'prev,next',
            'title',
            'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
            false,
            ''
        );
    }
})(jQuery);
```

From your comment, it seems as though the code is directly after the calendar widget panel, so you don't need the `document.ready` wrapper, since you are guaranteeing that the element already exists. You also don't need the  `Request.Url.Host` and `Request.Url.Port`, you can just use the absolute path and it will call back to the current domain.